# keytool error ： java.lang.RuntimeException:error，–alias is not a legal command

Tags: android, md5, android-mapview, keystore

when i try to get the md5 of my computer by the command "keytool -list –alias androiddebugkey –keystore d:\debug.keystore" , there comes with the error "keytool error ： java.lang.RuntimeException:error，–alias is not a legal command"

Answer (score 2):

If u r using eclipse, try using **["Keytoool for Eclipse"](http://keytool.sourceforge.net/)** . Hope it reduces the burden of getting MD5 key. FYI you need to use "keytool -v -list"  instead of "keytool -list" if you need all the type keys(MD5 , SHA etc.,).

Answer (score 0):

did you copy and paste the command? try to change `–alias` to `-alias` (note: `-` not `–`)